# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException Unable to locate element:method":"link text","selector":"http://

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, pageobjects

I'm unable to locate the element using any of the locator techniques.

So far I've tried- By.linkText, By.cssSelector & By.xpath but to no avail. This is happening when I try to login using a different java class. However, if I write all my code in a single java class with the following selector (By createAccount = By.cssSelector("a.createAccount");) this error is not seen.

```
<a class="createAccount" href="https://www.***.com/registration/" tabindex="9">
<span class="fontIconCreateAccount mdxFont" aria-hidden="true">
<span class="icon icon--pep">
<span class="icon__add-button"></span>
</span>
</span>
Create Account
</a>
```

Would appreciate suggestions.

EDIT : Added the corresponding Java code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class LoginPage {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
    }

    By createAccount = By.linkText("https://***.com/registration/");

    //By createAccount = By.cssSelector("a.createAccount");
    //By createAccount = By.xpath(".//*[@id='signInBottomInformationContainer']/a");
    public WebElement createAccountLink(){
        return driver.findElement(createAccount);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your java code?

Comment: First thing - By.linkText needs text of link ([related doc here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-link-text)), not href parameter. To find by href parameter use xpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user1502890, try this

```
By createAccount = By.linkText("Create Account");
```

OR

```
By createAccount = By.partialLinkText("Create Account");
```

If this do not solve the problem try to use WebDriverWait while finding the elements.